# How to use popen?

Tags: c, pipe, posix, ipc

I'm trying to do inter process communication with `stdin` and `stdout`. The Posix function I found is `popen`, but I failed to write a working sample code. Please help me get this work.

<edit1>
Do I have to use `dup`? I can see some examples found with Google using it. But the Linux manual of `dup` really does not help me understanding how to use that.
</edit1>

### a.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char *s;

    for(;;){
        scanf("%ms",&s);
        printf("%s\n",s);
        if(!strcmp(s,"quit")){
            free(s);
            printf("bye~\n");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        free(s);
    }
}
```

### b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fRead;
    FILE *fWrite;
    char *s;
    int i;

    fRead=popen("~/a.out","r");
    fWrite=popen("~/a.out","w");
    for(i=1;i<=10;++i){
        fprintf(fWrite,"%d",i);
        fscanf(fRead,"%ms",&s);
        printf("%s\n",s);
        free(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are aware that you are starting `a.out` twice, aren't you?

Comment: @alk I do see the problem, then how do I read the output at the same time?

Comment: Use `popen("~/a.out >output", "r")` and read `output`.

Comment: @xiver77, or use the `pipe()`/`dup()`/`fork()`/`exec()` to start the process with overridden IO, and then the `poll()` to multiplex the input/output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As defined by POSIX, Pipes are a unidirectional communication mechanism — they work in one direction only.  In order to redirect both standard input and standard output, you need to create two pipes — and the `popen` function cannot do that.

While slightly less convenient, it is not difficult to achieve what you want by using directly the system calls `fork`, `pipe`, `dup2` and `exec`:

```
rc = pipe(p1);
if(rc < 0) ...
rc = pipe(p2);
if(rc < 0) ...

rc = fork();
if(rc < 0) {
    ...
} else if(rc == 0) {
    /* child */
    close(p1[0]);
    close(p2[1]);
    dup2(p1[1], 1);
    dup2(p2[0], 0);
    execlp(...);
    exit(1);
} else {
    /* parent */
    close(p1[1]);
    close(p2[0]);
    ...
}
```

There are other solutions ­— you could use the `socketpair` system call to avoid the need for two pipes, or even use Unix domain sockets directly.