# Tasklist in C, Image Name filter

Tags: c, windows, cmd, tasklist

I'm running the tasklist command from a program written in C, the problem is that I need the program to return to the screen just the "Image Name" column omitting the other columns.  Is there any way to filter it to just leave me the name processes and not the PID column or other?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

printf("IP number:\t");
scanf("%s", ip);

sprintf(command, "tasklist /fo TABLE /nh /s %s", ip);
system(command);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `popen` instead of `system`, then you can process the output prior to displaying it.

Comment: Or pipe output to a file, for processing, before display. Use `>filename`

Comment: Can you show me a example with popen? I don't know how it works. @PaulR

Comment: Lots of examples right here on StackOverflow, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259086/how-to-use-popen