# How to execute listed ubuntu commands using c program in parent process without being redirected to child process

Tags: c

I have three files. First file contains commands which are needed to be executed  and this file is .txt file. Second file is output.txt file which stores the output of the command which has been executed. Third file is C program through which i will execute the commands from the first file. Now i have tried three methods which are available in c programming which are popen(), system() and execl() functions.

1. when i used popen() method it has worked fine, but for every command it is creating child process, i dont want that, for every command it should be executed in  single process which is parent process and  i just executed basics command like pwd and cd and my output is as follows:

COMMAND: `pwd`
OUTPUT: /home/basavaraj/Desktop/My_Folders/C

COMMAND: `cd /home/basavaraj/Documents && pwd`
OUTPUT: /home/basavaraj/Documents

COMMAND: `pwd`
OUTPUT: /home/basavaraj/Desktop/My_Folders/C

So, this is my output for those commands when i used cd and pwd in single command line, i got confirmed that child process is being created.
This is what i don't want to happen, for every command it should execute in parent process.

2. For system() function it is returning an integer, i want output which is string to be stored in output.txt file, so what should i do to store the output in .txt file.
3. For execl() function it is running only one command after executing one command it is terminating the whole C program, i want to execute each and every command from command text file, so what should be done to execute every command from command file.

Please help me with this, i'm stuck at every method, please explain what and how to do it, please explain in your comfort method and is there any other method's which i'm not aware, please feel free to tell about that.

EDIT: The source of this C-program:

```
while (fgets(command, bufferSize, input_file) != NULL)      
{         
    fprintf(shellPipe, "%s", command);                  
    while (fgets(output_buffer, sizeof(output_buffer), shellPipe) != NULL)          
       {         
           fprintf(output_file, "%s", output_buffer);         
       }      
}
```

Comment: If you want to execute the commands as part of your C program, you have to actually `open()` the file and read the commands and tokenize and parse them and choose diferent action inside of your program. No `system` no `popen` - actually reading the file, parsing and executing different C function that you wrote depending on tokens. This is typically "writing your own shell" type of task.

Comment: I'm opening the file and reading  the commands.

Comment: Please only add tags that are relevant to your question and avoid tag spamming.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the problem to be solved, why do you need to run it inside your process?

Comment: And what is purpose of the third file? Is it your program, that you want to create?

Comment: i want to prevent child process which is being created by all three functions which i mentioned in the question, so i need to prevent this from happening and i need to execute all the commands in the parent process itself. The third file stores the output of the commands which are executed in the form of string.

Comment: Please include the C-source of this program.

Comment: You cannot prevent a child process, because each command that you execute with either of these methods is in fact a child process. If you don't want a child process, then your C program must implement all commands by itself, and not rely on any exec-type functions to run them, as @KamilCuk mentioned.

Comment: There are commands to run and "builtins". You have to handle builtin separately and special within your code. Like in psueudocode `if (command[0] == "cd") { parse_cd_args(); chdir(args[1]); } else { system(....); }`

Comment: You are actually asking how to run a script (a text file with a sequence of commands is nothing else than a script) from a C program. The only problem is the script file is not executable. So the easiest solution is to make it executable (`chmod(...)`), then just run it using `popen()`. Although this does not prevent a child process, as I already mentioned.

Comment: @raj yeah I cannot prevent the child process, but thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @raj @Luuk @KamilCuk                                                                                                        `while (fgets(command, bufferSize, input_file) != NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(shellPipe, "%s", command);
        
        while (fgets(output_buffer, sizeof(output_buffer), shellPipe) != NULL) 
        {
        fprintf(output_file, "%s", output_buffer);
        }

    }`      I'm using this method to store the output in output.txt file, but that file is empty even after code termination, nothing is being stored in it.   What should i do please help.

Comment: I added the source of this to your question (it is better readable there, than in the comments).  The question remains unanswered, because it is unclear how `output_buffer` is defined before this piece of code is executed, so with current info it is pretty clear that the condition of your inner while-loop is not true.

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259086/how-to-use-popen/30259507#30259507 as well as `popen()` man page: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html says that pipe created by `popen()` is **unidirectional**; you can either read or write to it, you can't do both.

Comment: Just `popen()` the shell and provide your commands file as standard input to the shell, like this: `popen("/bin/sh <commands.txt", "r")`, then capture output from `popen()`.

Comment: You are doing something very unusual. Most programs running shell commands do it by running /bin/sh in a child process. popen(3) and system(3) also do that. Are you 100% sure that a child process doesn't work for you? Why? Why are your requirements so special?

Comment: @pts: See the 3 `COMMANDS` in the question.   Executing `cd` in a sub-process does not change the directory of the parent process.

Comment: @pts i want every command to run in single process which goes like  command execution then output in output.txt file, then second command execution, output in same text file after the first command output and  goes on like this till all the commands are executed.

Comment: That's what you didn't mention initially that you want each command executed individually; on the contrary, your example with `cd` and `pwd` clearly suggests that you want to execute all commands in a single session. If you want to execute each command individually, then executing `cd` will have no impact at the following `pwd`, unless you implement commands like `cd` and `pwd` yourself (and perhaps other that you need, we still don't know what is your actual problem).

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, on a high level? Writing your own shell? What is the purpose of your program? Perhaps your goal can be achieved differently and you are going the wrong way in design...

Comment: If all you need is changing the current directory of the parent process, then you can achieve this by running `pwd >pwd.tmp` as the last command in the child process, and after it finishes, read the file `pwd.tmp` in the parent process, and call chdir(2).

Comment: It's also unusual to change the current directory of the parent process. Programs and processes are typically not organized this way. Also it introduces state, which can cause surprises in the future. You may want to organize it differently.

Answer (score 0):

Assume `commands.txt` is the input file with commands, `output.txt` is the file that stores the output. As your commands must be executed by the shell anyway (otherwise you would have to re-implement the shell, which you probably are not planning to do), the simplest method to achieve what you want is:

```
system("/bin/sh <commands.txt >output.txt");
```

However, if you want to do something more with the output from commands than just write it to a file (eg. process it somehow in your program), you can use something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *inputfile, *outputfile;

  char line[500];

  inputfile = popen("/bin/sh <commands.txt", "r");
  outputfile = fopen("output.txt", "w");

  while ( fgets( line, sizeof line, inputfile))
  {
    fprintf(outputfile, "%s", line);
  }

  pclose(inputfile);
  fclose(outputfile);
}
```

Also, if you can make your `commands.txt` file **executable** (for example by using `chmod()` function in your program, if the user running program is also the owner of the file), you can replace the `popen("/bin/sh <commands.txt", "r")` call in above code by just `popen("./commands.txt", "r")` - everything else remains the same.

Comment: thanks for your code, but i need to execute every command in single process, i have tried this method, but this is not what i want